# Command not found when trying send zip file through ftp

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to send a zip with variable timestamp to another server through ftp. But when im trying to execute the shell its showing Command not found error. $DESSEND contains the zip file location. Guide me how to solve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename = $DESSEND/T56_OBL001_${DATEFIX}.zip
hostname="IP Address"
username="Username"
password="Password"
ftp -nv $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password

binary
put $filename
quit
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error?

Comment: 553 filename not found

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close here-doc.Try

```
#!/bin/bash
filename = $DESSEND/T56_OBL001_${DATEFIX}.zip
hostname="IP Address"
username="Username"
password="Password"
ftp -nv $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
binary
put $filename
quit
EOF
```

And make sure your variables DESSEND and DATEFIX are set